Docker compose run results in "no configuration file provided: not found" (with -p)
I have a docker compose project. Something like this:
services:
  service_1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./src/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./PROD.env
  service_2:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./src_2/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./PROD.env

Service doesn't have a command neither in compose file, nor in Dockerfile. So it stops right after start. That's ok. I want to start it with a specific command on demand:
docker compose -p project_name run service_1 python app/main.py

But it always results in a message:
no configuration file provided: not found

Though, if I ran
docker compose -p project_name logs

or
docker compose -p project_name images

or any other command without service name, it works. So run should be working as well, right?
Also, there are services in the project, that are up all the time. But when I try to use the run command on them, I get the same result.
I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows.

Docker Desktop v 4.33.1
Docker version 27.1.1
Docker Compose version v2.29.1-desktop.1


Are you in the folder where your compose file lives when you are running this command?

I am. But if I understand correctly, since I use -p project_name, it should not matter. Other commands can be run from any folder, only run seems to be problematic(

Other commands would need at least one object to be running for that project I would guess. What are your versions of compose and Docker? I wasn’t able to reproduce when I tested the same yesterday.

Added versions to the post. Yes, there are services in the project that are up all the time.
